# USB 3.0 Type E, where it connects

Tags: usb, motherboard

So, I was looking for front panels for my PC and found this [curious panel](https://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-3-1-Front-Panel-Header-Type-E-M-to-Type-C-F-Motherboard-Expansion-Cable-K/223588393036?hash=item340ee8204c:g:~8sAAOSw-0FdLDHc).

It has this connector they call USB 3.0 Type E and the connector to the motherboard looks different than usual.

[image]

[image]

What is this connector?

Comment: @Moab  Is this USB-E a standard port though? I've never saw one of these, only those USB 3.0 blue connectors. Google also doesn't help me either

Comment: @Moab it can be confusing but what are the odds of a motherboard having this connector? And also, feel free to write an answer and I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a usb-e motherboard port, I doubt you will see it anywhere else. USB-c is the new standard for usb connections and e is a variation of this.

Its just a way to port usb-c female to the back of the case from the motherboard. Its is just a usb-e male to usb-c female adapter cable. Your motherboard must have a usb-e connection to use this cable

Answer (score 2):

No no no ...
This is a USB 3.1 Gen 2 (10Gbps) connector, I have one in my Asus X370 Prime motherboard...
So this is the double of the speed of USB 3.1 Gen 1 or USB 3.0, 5Gbps.
I have a USB-E to USB-C cable to connect to an external disk cage with an SSD, and it flies...!

Comment: This is the correct answer. Type E doesn't officially exist. Source: https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB3p1_Front_Panel_CabCon_Implment_Doc_Rev1p1.pdf